# Curl error code 7 could not connect the host on port 80

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am using below code and getting "Failed to connect to api.textlocal.in port 80: Connection timed out" error. I was able to use the same y'day as well but now suddenly facing the issue. I am using Godaddy's shared hosting. I have checked with them they are saying so such firewall blockage is there also checked from API vendor Textlocal they also told the same(No IP restriction or firewall blockage). Could some one help me out from here.

I can get response from google.com as in commented block.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump("Curl Error No-".curl_errno($ch));
    var_dump("<br/>Curl Error Description-".curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    /*
    $ch = curl_init("http://google.com");    // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print($data);
    */
```